# Multiple dates in column 'date'. Numbers in column 'Value'. Pull a sum of 3 days of 'Value' before and after EACH specific 'Date'

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL in Oracle:

Dataset Example:

```
Search_date  Value
01-Feb-2016      5
02-Feb-2016      4
03-Feb-2016      9
04-Feb-2016     10 
05-Feb-2016     12
06-Feb-2016     10
07-Feb-2016      7
```

So...... If I set a where condition of search_date = '04-Feb-2016' it would return the following:

**Search_date,  Before_Period, After_Period,**

**04-Feb-2016** **18** (9 + 4 + 5)..., **29** (10 + 12 + 7)

But I would like to pull this for every distinct date

Comment: what did you manage already? are there any problems with your code/SQL? Or do you just want us to do your homework? ;)

Comment: Nope. It's for work. This is just a small piece of a much larger query that will hopefully pull some insightful analysis. Just stuck on this one piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SUM()` [analytical (windowed) function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DataSet ( Search_date, Value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-02-01',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-02',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-03',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-04', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-05', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-06', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-07',  7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT  search_date,
        COALESCE(
          SUM( value ) OVER (
            ORDER BY Search_date
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
          ),
          0
        ) AS before_period,
        COALESCE(
          SUM( value ) OVER (
            ORDER BY Search_date
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
          ),
          0
        ) AS after_period
FROM    DataSet;
```

**Output**:

```
SEARCH_DATE BEFORE_PERIOD AFTER_PERIOD
----------- ------------- ------------
01-FEB-16               0           52 
02-FEB-16               5           48 
03-FEB-16               9           39 
04-FEB-16              18           29 
05-FEB-16              28           17 
06-FEB-16              40            7 
07-FEB-16              50            0
```

If you want just the 3 days before/after then change `UNBOUNDED` to `3`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: @Wells If this or another answer has answered your question then you can mark that answer as accepted to indicate that the question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try [aggregate (windowing clause)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97640) functions:

```
select dt, 
sum(val) over(order by dt  rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev,  
sum(val) over(order by dt  rows between 1 following and 3 following) as next 
from t order by dt;
```

Output:

```
DT          PREV    NEXT
02/01/2016          18
02/01/2016  5       23
02/02/2016  10      31
02/03/2016  14      32
02/04/2016  18      29
02/05/2016  23      17
02/06/2016  31      7
02/07/2016  32
```

Comment: Just ran it on my dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most performant solution (not tested with oracle, but should make no difference):

```
select a.dat search_date, (select sum(b.val) from john b where b.dat < a.dat) before_period, (select sum(c.val) from john c where c.dat > a.dat) after_period from john a;
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| search_date | before_period | after_period |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| 2016-02-01  |          NULL |           52 |
| 2016-02-02  |             5 |           48 |
| 2016-02-03  |             9 |           39 |
| 2016-02-04  |            18 |           29 |
| 2016-02-05  |            28 |           17 |
| 2016-02-06  |            40 |            7 |
| 2016-02-07  |            50 |         NULL |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Was also thinking about trying multiple self joins, but.....